# Show entry versions on front-end

Tags: entries

If I have entry versioning turned on is there any way that I can show details of previous entry versions on the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way using native EE tags, but using the query module I'm sure this could be done or by creating a plugin perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here http://www.sidd3.com/get-entry-revisions-in-expressionengine/

It would be helpful for you.

Comment: That link seems to be dead.

Comment: I have developed a plugin for this purpose. One can download from here: http://www.sidd3.com/entry-revisions-plugin/